# Write a statement in propositional logic that says $x \in A Δ B$. Solution should use at most two connectives.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, propositional-calculus, logic-translation

We have two sets $A$ and $B$ and some object $x$. Let’s introduce two propositional variables:

- $a$, which states that $x \in A$, and
- $b$, which states that $x \in B$.

I get as far as $(a \lor b) \land \lnot(a \land b)$. But the questions asks for a solution that the total number of connectives used is just two. I have used 4: $\lor$, $\land$, $\lnot$ and another $\land$. How can I reduce even further?

Connected to this question:
[What does the connection between 𝐴△𝐵△C and A <=> B <=> C?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3672117/what-does-the-connection-between-c-and-a-b-c)

Comment: Is "not" really a connective? It doesn't actually connect anything the way "and" and "or" does.

Comment: the questions I am working through consider "not" as a connective. I would agree, since "not" connects proposition p to its opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symmetric difference $\triangle$ has essentially the logical meaning of the "exclusive or".

More precisely, $x \in A \triangle B$ means that 
\begin{align}\tag{1}
(x \in A) \, \leftrightarrow \, \lnot (x \in B)
\end{align}
which is a statement with exactly two logical connectives, $\leftrightarrow$ and $\lnot$.

Indeed, according to the semantics of the [biconditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional) $\leftrightarrow$, $(1)$ is true if and only if either $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$, or $x \notin A$ and $x \in B$, as required by the definition of $x \in A \triangle B$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can see the biconditional stating that ∈ and ∉, but how does it state x∉A  and ∈? The => states that if x is in A, then it is not in B. The <= states that if x is not in B, then it is in A. Where in the implication does it refer to x not being in A implying that x is in B?

Comment: @azxz - The biconditional $X↔Y$ is true if and only if $X$ and $Y$ have the same truth value, i.e. if and only if either $X$ and $Y$ are both true, or $X$ and $Y$ are both false. Now, read this with $X=x∈A$ and $Y=¬(x∈B)$ and you get my answer.

Comment: I get it. What I described earlier described the case when both X and Y are true. The case when both are false deals with the case I asked about. Got it thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do $x \in A \oplus x \in B$

Here, the $\oplus$ is the symbol for the XOR